# Attaching text file into word document Python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am learning **python-docx** python module.

I am not getting how I could attach a `.txt` file into word document and save it.

I am able to write file content into a word like below.

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        document.add_paragraph(line)
document.save('wordfile.docx')
```

But I want to attach `.txt` file instead of writing content into word.

Expected output:

[image]
Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Please explain, are you asking about how to open file with Python or how to append to file ?

Comment: I am trying to generate word document using python and I want to attach textfile into word document.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104908/how-to-create-docx-files-with-python

Comment: When you say "attach", do you mean actually adding the file as an attachment to the Word document, or do you mean adding its contents to the end of the document? (since you could do either with a text file) The `python-docx` third party library does not appear to support adding attachments, like you could from VBA, so you may need to look into ways of doing this using other libraries or tools.

Comment: @Grismar Can you suggest any way, that would be helpful for us :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job from Word (VBA) itself:

```
Public Function RetrieveOLEInfo(fileExt As String)
    Dim regKey As String
    Dim oleServer As String

    fileExt = "txt"
    regKey = "HKEY_Classes_Root\."
    RetrieveOLEInfo = System.PrivateProfileString("", regKey & fileExt, "")
End Function
Sub Test()
    Documents.Add
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        ClassType:=RetrieveOLEInfo("txt"), FileName:="c:\0000\test.txt", LinkToFile:=True, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconLabel:="test.txt"
End Sub
```

The job would be to make sure you have Office Interop stuff installed (I don't, so I can't test) and rewrite the script into Python, an examples of someone doing something similar here: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/196521/how-to-insert-or-embed-a-html-file-in-to-a-word-doc