# Export nicely formatted text to word doc from python

Tags: python

I have developed a python script that parses through word docs, and extracts the acronyms and their definitions. Is there a clean way I can nicely format and then export these definitions perhaps as an svg such that I can then paste these in a word doc. I'm hoping to produce something like the following http://www.fao.org/3/y4922e/y4922e0o.htm and then lift it into my reports

Comment: This might be helpful: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104908/how-to-create-docx-files-with-python>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library : [svgwrite](https://pypi.org/project/svgwrite/)
In the documentation you have an example :

```
import svgwrite

dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', profile='tiny')
dwg.add(dwg.line((0, 0), (10, 0), stroke=svgwrite.rgb(10, 10, 16, '%')))
dwg.add(dwg.text('Test', insert=(0, 0.2), fill='red'))
dwg.save()
```

Another solution could be using an visualization library like [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/index.html) :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib # if abbreviating this, use "as mpl"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
set_matplotlib_formats('png', 'pdf')

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheetname='IvT')

sns.set_style("white")
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
plt.xlabel('Test', fontsize=18)
plt.title ('Test', fontsize=22)
#sns.boxplot(df[['Short total']])
sns.boxplot(df[['Short total']])
plt.show()


plt.savefig("test.svg", format="svg")
```